# Images are not removed from disk after clearing cache AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I tried to clear cache bit the size of the app does not become significantly smaller.

My app size is about 30MB plus 45MB for cached images.

This is how I attempted to clear cache:

```
 [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
 [[AFImageDownloader defaultURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
 AFAutoPurgingImageCache *imageCache = [AFImageDownloader defaultInstance].imageCache;
 [imageCache removeAllImages];
```

- On my iPhone 6 iOS10 the size of the app did not get smaller.
- On Simulator inside app files `com.alamofire.imagedownloader/fsCachedData` all the files are still there

This is how I download images using AFNetworking (3.1.0):

```
#import "AFImageDownloader.h"

[photoImageView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:thumb] placeholderImage:myCachedImage success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                [self setPhotoImage:image];
            } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                [self setupPlaceholder];
            }];
```

Comment: i found that caching not always working in simulator, try real device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See follows:

1. `AFAutoPurgingImageCache *imageCache = [AFImageDownloader defaultInstance].imageCache;` The `imageCache` is stored in the memory, it is useless to do `[imageCache removeAllImages];`
2. You just need to do `[[AFImageDownloader defaultURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];`. It is the only API that apple offers to clear the `URLCache`.
3. You find the `fsCachedData` is not removed when you call `removeAllCachedResponses`. It is because apple has its own mechanism to clear the disk data. Maybe it will clear the disk data in every 7 days as i  searched, but i can not make sure.
4. I think it is interesting to see how the others use `fsCachedData`. [Should I clear the fsCachedData folder myself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233870/should-i-clear-the-fscacheddata-folder-myself)
5. I hope it will help u.

Comment: Any solution for this , as I am facing same issue for every time download image case. Just want app should download every time image from the same URL. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We are seeing this in one of our apps as well. According to this http://blog.airsource.co.uk/2014/10/11/nsurlcache-ios8-broken/, its an iOS 8 bug which Apple will have corrected in the iOS 8.1 update today.

So to answer your question: No, you shouldn't have to delete the cache yourself and with some luck Apple's fix really will clean up the old data. If for some reason not, you should be able to delete it yourself without any problems.

I've verified that iOS 8.1 does indeed correct the issue. The user must launch the app once after update for the cache to be cleared however.

Comment: Why are you talking about iOS 8, and link to a blogpost from 2014? We are 2016 now and most people are using iOS 10. I experience the same problem as the original poster but I doubt this has something to do with a bug in iOS 8 (which was fixed in iOS8.1).

Answer (score 0):

This code works for AFNetworking 3.1:

```
        [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

        AFImageDownloader *imageDownloader = [AFImageDownloader defaultInstance];
        NSURLCache *urlCache = imageDownloader.sessionManager.session.configuration.URLCache;
        [urlCache removeAllCachedResponses];

        [imageDownloader.imageCache removeAllImages];
```